# DynamoDB begins with not returning expected results

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using NodeJS and DynamoDB. I'm never used DynamoDB before, and primary a C# developer (where this would simply just be a `.Where(x => x...`) call, not sure why Amazon made it any more complicated then that). I'm trying to simply just query the table based on if an id starts with certain characters. For example, we have the year as the first 2 characters of the `Id` field. So something like this: `180192`, so the year is 2018. The `20` part is irrelevant, just wanted to give a human readable example. So the Id starts with either `18` or `17` and I simply want to query the db for all rows that Id starts with `18` (for example, could be 17 or whatever). I did look at the documentation and I'm not sure I fully understand it, here's what I have so far that is just returning all results and not the expected results.

```
   let params = {
        TableName: db.table,
        ProjectionExpression: "id,CompetitorName,code",
        KeyConditionExpression: "begins_with(id, :year)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':year': '18'
        }
    return db.docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

So as you can see, I'm thinking that this would be a `begins_with` call, where I look for 18 against the Id. But again, this is returning all results (as if I didn't have KeyConditionExpression at all).

Would love to know where I'm wrong here. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So I guess `begin_with` won't work since it only works on strings and my id is not a string. As per commenters suggestion, I can use `BETWEEN`, which even that is not working either. I either get back all the results or `Query key condition not supported` error (if I use `.scan`, I get back all results, if I use `.query` I get the error)

Here is the code I'm trying.

```
        let params = {
        TableName: db.table,
        ProjectionExpression: "id,CompetitorName,code",
        KeyConditionExpression: "id BETWEEN :start and :end",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':start': 18000,
            ':end': 189999
        }
    };

return db.docClient.query(params).promise();
```

Comment: Is the ID field a string or number?

Comment: I believe it's a number, I don't have access to the schema, but looking at the rest of the code we pass in a parseInt(id) so I'm guessing number.

Comment: I've tried passing `18` instead of `'18'` however I get this error: `Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: begins_with, operand type: N` if I try to put quotes around it, I get this error: `One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type`

Comment: You can't use `begins_with` with a number.  It's strings only.  You have to use `BETWEEN '180000' AND '1899999'`.  However, this will be a terrible way to do it assuming there are IDs with more than six digits. (You'd have to make a comparison for each digit range).

Comment: That won't work, since we have ids with varying digits. Is there seriously no way to just do a simple where clause? I find this highly surprising the level of difficulty just to make a simple where clause (sorry for the rant, just very frustrating)

Comment: Describe a little bit more about the project. Is it possible to use ORM? 
Take a look at [Dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#querybeginswithvalue)
In this case, you need to define `year` as a rangeKey.

Comment: No I don't think so, the project is pretty simple, we are just getting data from our DynamoDB database. Instead of grabbing all of it, I was tasked to grab them by year. The problem is the way we format the id, we have the year as the first two digits, and then a bunch of other numbers that I'm not sure how it's relevant. So really all I want to do is just grab any column that's id starts with a given two digit number (17 = 2017, 18 = 2018).

Comment: I know this doesn't help since I'm guessing whoever is reading this is a javascript developer, but literally all I'm trying to do is this (this is the C# version): `IQueryable.Where(x => x.Id.substring(0, 2) == 18).ToList();` just a simple where clause is all I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my attempt at using `BETWEEN` which still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if there's no actual solution for what I was originally trying to do unfortunately. Which is a huge downfall of DynamoDB. There really needs to be some way to do 'where' using the values of columns, like you can in virtually any other language. However, I have to admit, part of the problem was the way that `id` was structured. You shouldn't have to rely on the id to get info out of it. Anyways, I did find another column `DateofFirstCapture` which using with contains (all the dates are not the same format, it's a mess) and using a year `2018` or `2017` seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch data by id, add it as the partition key. If you want to get data by part of the string, you can use "begins with" on sort key.

[image]

> begins_with (a, substr)— true if the value of attribute a begins with a particular substring.

source: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Comment: how can we run begins_with using aws cli dynamodb command assuming we have a sort key?

Comment: @FisherCoder you must always have primary key (aka partition key) otherwise dynamodb has no clue in which server your data is to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

`begins_with` and `between` can only be used on sort keys.
For `query` you must always supply partition key.

So if you change your design to have unique partition key (or unique combo of partition/sort keys) and strings like `180192` as sort key you will be able to query `begins_with(sortkey, ...)`.